# Spring handleBindException how to override

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

Пытаюсь переопределить метод:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ControllersExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleBindException(BindException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, new ErrorDto(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(),
                "Invalid credentials! Password should has min 8 symbols and all fields are required"),
                headers, status, request);
    }
}
==============================
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ErrorDto {
    private int status;
    private String message;
}
```

Пытаюсь переопределить так, чтобы он возвращал внятный ответ клиенту, но получается такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И, как не пытаясь извратиться с ResponseEntity, всегда возвращает пустой json. Как это можно поправить?

Comment: Переведите заголовки вопросов на русский

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятнее всего у вас бросается какое-то другое исключение, не `BindException`

В классе `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` помимо `handleBindException` содержится ещё целая куча других `handle***`. Некоторые из них по-умолчанию возвращают 400 код и пустое тело.

Посмотрите отладчиком какое исключение приходит в `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException` и какой `handle***` вызывается

Upd: при использовании `@Valid` и `@Size(min=10)` бросается исключение `MethodArgumentNotValidException` которое можно обработать переопределив метод `handleMethodArgumentNotValid`

Comment: это Exception,возникающий в от аннотации `@Valid` . Понятно, если я  просто повешу проверку на наличие ошибок в `bindingResult`и потом проброшу свое исключение, все работает, но мне необходимо сократить наличие кода

Comment: @Anastasiya я же ничего не писал про bindingResult и бросание своих исключений, откуда вы это взяли?

Comment: Я делала так до того как унаследовалась от `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`)) Теперь просто появилась необходимость перенести проверку `if(bindingResult.hasErrors())` переопределением метода, просто уточнение

Comment: @Anastasiya Обновил ответ, если это не поможет - добавьте в вопрос что больше подробностей (код контроллера, модели и т.д.)

Comment: Вы правы) Спасибо, моя оплошность